# how to connect sql server database in C++ code?

Tags: c++, sql-server, visual-c++, c++-cli

I have a project of C++ windows form. Now, I want to store the data in my SQL server database.
So, how can I connect my database from inside my C++ code and how to write an insert query?

I used the following code but it throws an exception that cannot open or cannot found the database.

```
SqlConnection^ con = gcnew SqlConnection();
int i = 0;  

con->ConnectionString = "Data Source=122.179.151.229\EIEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ICAST_IMS;Uid=developer;pwd=dev@12345";
con->Open();

SqlCommand^ com = gcnew SqlCommand();
com->Connection = con;
com->CommandText = "INSERT INTO image_analysis (nodule_count, nodularity) VALUES (final_nodule_count, 'final_nodularity')";
com->ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Once you get the connection string issue sorted out you are going to find an error in your insert statement also. You are trying to insert final_nodule_count but what is that? It will fail with an invalid column name final_nodule_count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem it's your connection string, you include an "\" which is a special character, you need to try doing "\\" so the system recognize you're inserting an "\".

Hope this helps you!

Comment: This is an ex. of a connection I made "Password=1234;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=Entrecom;Data Source=LAPTOP-B2CORTSA\\SQLEXPRESS"... but i see now that u solved your problem, that's nice :)